# Plot multiple fitdist objects in same the plot with different colors?

Tags: r, plot, normal-distribution, fitdistrplus

I have a list of `fitdist` objects, which I have stored using this piece of code.

```
norm_dist_res <- list()
for(i in 1:10)
{
  x <- 1+(8000*(i-1))
  y <- 8000*i
  print (x)
  print(y)
  norm_dist_res[[i]] = norm_dist_res[[i]] <- fitdist(data=as.vector(g_all_p$data[x:y,]), distr="norm")

}
```

Is there a way to plot all the normal distributions extracted from `fittest` with a different color to show how the data is distributed?

Or in general how to visualize multiple normal distributions?

Comment: What is the content of a `fitdist` object? This function is not part of base R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are estimating the parameters of a normal distribution, so just plot the densities.

```
## Don't no what g_all_p is, so simplifying the data
library(fitdistrplus)
norm_dist_res <- list()
for(i in 1:10)
{
  norm_dist_res[[i]] = norm_dist_res[[i]] <- fitdist(data=rnorm(10), distr="norm")

}
```

Then just plot using `lines` and changing the colour

```
x = seq(-5, 5, length.out=100)
plot(x, type="n", ylim=c(0, 1), xlim=range(x))
for(i in 1:10) {
  est = norm_dist_res[[i]]$estimate
  lines(x, dnorm(x, est[1], est[2]), col="grey90")
}
```

To get

[image]